# jquery masonry gutters enlarge after browser refresh

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, jquery-masonry

Just as I thought I was making progress with making Masonry more responsive...

I'm calling Masonry in with this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var CollManag = (function() {
    var $ctCollContainer = $('#grid'),
    collCnt = 1,
    init = function() {
        changeColCnt();
        initEvents();
        initPlugins();
    },
    changeColCnt = function() {
        var w_w = $(window).width();
        if( w_w <= 480 ) n = 1;
        else if( w_w <= 700 ) n = 2;
        else n = 3;
    },
    initEvents = function() {
        $(window).on( 'smartresize.CollManag', function( event ) {
            changeColCnt();
        });
    },
    initPlugins = function() {
        $ctCollContainer.imagesLoaded( function(){
            $ctCollContainer.masonry({
                itemSelector : '.box_item',
                columnWidth : function( containerWidth ) {
                    return containerWidth / n;
                },
                isAnimated : true,
                animationOptions: {
                    duration: 250
                }
            });
        });

    };
    return { init: init };
})();
CollManag.init();
```

});

It changes masonry columns based on viewport width.

I've stripped my HTML/CSS right back so that I just have some images wrapped in a div (.box_item). These divs have percentage based widths (i'm aware of the browser rounding off issue using %).

Everything was working nicely, when I reduced my browsers width, my grid changed from 3, 2, 1 column accordingly. I was especially happy with the spacings in between my containers (everything looked equal).

If I resized my browser down to 700px, all the gutters we're equal (slightly larger on the far right hand side due to browsers rounding off my dimensions). If I refreshed my browser at this view port, the gutters changed width slightly. If I resized my browser by 1px, my grid spacing reset.

People accessing certain viewports is more important than me resizing my browser to them :) Any idea what might be causing this problem? 99% sure its not CSS related, as i've stripped everything right back.

Update: Have replaced the original script with this one below (problem persists):

```
// load masonry / change layout based on view port
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $container = $('#grid');
    var gutter = 20;
    var min_width = 230;
    $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
        $container.masonry({
            itemSelector : '.box_item',
            gutterWidth: gutter,
            isAnimated: true,
              columnWidth: function( containerWidth ) {
                var box_width = (((containerWidth - 2*gutter)/3) | 0) ;

                if (box_width < min_width) {
                    box_width = (((containerWidth - gutter)/2) | 0);
                }

                if (box_width < min_width) {
                    box_width = containerWidth;
                }

                $('.box_item').width(box_width);

                return box_width;
              }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: this code is certainly doing the rounds on stackoverflow!

Comment: I think i've narrowed this down a little. looks like the script is calculating the view port including the scroll bars, not excluding them. If I make my page tall, with no scroll bars, the issue doesn't appear.

Comment: It does seem that `n` is being calculated in `changeColCnt` based on the window's width rather than the masonry container. Does the situation improve at all if you do the if-else's with the widths in `columnWidth : function( containerWidth ) {
  //calculate n here                  
  return containerWidth / n;
                },`

Comment: Also, consider the possibility that (when a resize event triggers) masonry gathers all the items in the container's corner, calculates width, then arranges them. If when the items are 'collapsed' the page height doesn't require a vertical scrollbar and after the items are laid out the pages does require one, I'm not sure a page resize event is triggered and masonry may still think its container is the same width as without the vertical scrollbars.

Comment: @frozenkoi didn't make any difference. I'm using a different variation of the script above and the issue still persists!

Comment: If you add, lets say, a DIV with a height equal to the window's height (so that there's always a vertical scrollbar even if the masonry stuff was removed) is your problem still present? If so, I think it's because of the way masonry handles resizes and scrollbars, and log a bug report with the author (Desandro)

Comment: @frozenkoi No scroll bars = no bug :) Will file a bug with desandro.